# GMP ceiling function

Tags: c, math, gmp

I'd like to find the ceiling of the square root of a very large number with GMP. In C, `ceil(sqrt(n))`.

The GMP square root for integers truncates the result, so the square root of 10 would be reported as 3. Floating point square root works as expected, but I need to take the next greatest integer. `mpf_get_d` rounds towards zero, but otherwise does what I want. How can I get the ceiling of the square root of a large number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there some specific reason to not use `mpf_ceil()`? Sounds like the mots logical step to me, unless I miss something.

Edit: After rereading your question, any reason to treat the numbers as integers over floating point?

Comment: Ah.. I didn't see that. I was looking in the float arithmetic and float conversion sections; it was in the miscellaneous section. I searched for various combinations of "GMP ceiling float function" without success.

Comment: I need an integer in the end, and I'd like to convert back to one as soon as possible. The square root is the only part of the computation that should be anything but an integer.

Comment: Converting to floating-point will definitely work but you need to make sure that you do it with enough precision and that you correctly round the result before converting back to an integer. In that case, my answer with the +/- 1 is probably simpler and easier to verify.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a quick-and-dirty trick:

```
ceil( sqrt(n) ) = trunc_sqrt(n - 1) + 1
```

where `trunc_sqrt(n)` is GMP's integer square root function that you are currently using.

This should work for all integers `n > 0`.